# www redirection not working on Wordpress on Openshift

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, openshift

I've setup a wordpress application on Openshift and I added 2 aliases (www.mysite.ma - mysite.ma). I followed the instructions to create a CNAME record, and I did so using CloudFlare. I've also changed my wordpress settings for the new URL.

My DNS Records on CloudFlare :

```
www -> myapp.rhcloud.com
@ -> myapp.rhcloud.com
```

When I visit **www.mysite.ma**, I can see my normal Wordpress site. But when I go to **mysite.ma**, it returns a 404 error with a changed link (**https://mysite.ma/app**)

I tried to modify my .htaccess file to the following :

```
RewriteEngine on 

# Uncomment the following lines to force HTTPS
#RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https 
#RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

# WordPress Defaults
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]


# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On


RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.mysite.ma$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.ma/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

But nothing changed, even when I do a ping request to **www.mysite.ma** and **myapp.rhcloud.com** I get the same IP Adress, not for **mysite.ma**

Thanks.

Comment: When you get a changed link, then there's some redirect in your webserver's configuration.

Comment: _"even when I do a ping request to www.mysite.ma and myapp.rhcloud.com I get the same IP Adress, not for mysite.ma"_ - that sounds rather like a problem with your DNS configuration. It's not WordPress' or your webserver's fault in that case - because they can not do anything wrong on requests that do not even reach them, but go to a different IP address altogether ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try http://wwwizer.com/ service:

Point

```
www to yourapp.rhcloud.com
mysite.ma to 174.129.25.170
```

wwwizer does a 301 redirect from 
`mysite.ma to www.mysite.ma`

It's free, you don't have to create an account to use this service.

Comment: Just to make it clear, they have a free domain redirect from the websiteyoupoint.com to www.websiteyoupoint.com. You can read more details about it here http://wwwizer.com/naked-domain-redirect. All you have to do is point your website.com to 174.129.25.170

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this;

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.mysite.ma$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.ma/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Try this;

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.ma [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.ma/$1 [L,R=301]
```